# how to unmount a function in useEffect (react js)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

test function dose not unmount and wen i click on correectAnswer the last function (test) is steal running and again test function will run and then when the last test function achieve to 0 we go to loser page.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    haveTime: 10
})

const [states] = useState({
    correct: "question",
    step: "loser"
})

const test = (timer) => {
    let haveTime = 10
    let time = setInterval(() => {
        haveTime -= 1;
        setState({ haveTime })
        // console.log(state.haveTime)
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(time)
        dispatch(getNameStep(states.step))
    }, timer);
}

const correectAnswer = () => {
    if (index === 9) {
        dispatch(getNameStep(stateForWinner.step))
    }
    else {
        dispatch({
            type: "indexIncrease"
        })
        test(10000)
    }

}

let { question, correct_answer } = details.question[index];

useEffect(() => {
    test(10000)
}, [])
```

Comment: Your questions is not clear. Can you simplify it by removing extra code. Apparently you are using some sort of reducer here like Redux.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code.
First you are combining setInterval with setTimeout which is not a good idea just because of the amount of coordination that needs to happen.

Second to clear an interval or a timeout you need to do it from within the useEffect by returning a function.

Third you have no "dependencies" in your useEffect.

Look at this code that use in one my apps:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
        SetSearchFilter(SearchLocal, State.Reversed);
    }, 250)
    
    // this is how you clear a timeout from within a use effect
    // by returning a function that does the disposing
    return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn);
}, [SearchLocal]);//here you need to add the actual dependencies of your useEffect
```

Lastly you need to breakdown your useEffect to perform a "single effect". Combining "too much stuff" into a single use effect is not good because then it is very difficult to debug and to achieve what you want.

You need to break down your useEffect into smaller useEffects.

You need to tell the useEffect when you want it to run by adding the dependencies.  This way you know that a particular useEffect will run for ecxample if the "nextStep" has changed or if the test has reached the end.